# SAS: convert string binary to character

Tags: binary, sas, character

I have a data set with a string binary `01001101`. Now I want to convert this string to character `M`.

SAS Formats and Informats did not lead to my expected result, because I did not found a suitable one.

```
data temp2;
  bit = '01001101';
  text = put (bit,binary.);
run;
```

How can I convert the string binary to character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INPUT not PUT and $BINARY not BINARY.

```
text = input (bit,$binary.);
```